# pymongo loop list dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pymongo

I am using pymongo and I am doing a query on structure that is basically a nest dict inside my document.

From what I have read the best way to handle this is to turn the pymongo cursor into a list and try to loop over the listed dictionary. My data now looks like this.

```
>>> myDict
[{'nestedDict': {'c': '3', 'a': '1', 'b': '2'}}]
```

how can loop this to get the keys values of a, b and c?

got it

```
>>> for key, value in myDict[0]['nestedDict'].items():
...     print(key, value)
... 
c 3
a 1
b 2

>>>
```

Comment: What the original document look like? Can we see the query? What is your mongod version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need you something like this?

```
myDict[0]['nestedDict']['b']
'2'
```

Comment: Thanks this is putting me closer. I am just trying to figure out how to make this work in loop now.

Comment: Got it >>> for key, value in myDict[0]['nestedDict'].items():
...     print(key, value)
... 
c 3
a 1
b 2
>>>